# Jetpack Compose: Make full-screen (absolutely positioned) component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

How can I go about making a composable deep down within the render tree full screen, similar to how the `Dialog` composable works?

Say, for example, when a use clicks an image it shows a full-screen preview of the image without changing the current route.

I could do this in CSS with `position: absolute` or `position: fixed` but how would I go about doing this in Jetpack Compose? Is it even possible?

One solution would be to have a composable at the top of the tree that can be passed another composable as an argument from somewhere else in the tree, but this sounds kind of messy. Surely there is a better way.

Comment: Could you please clarify, what do you mean by "changing the current route"?

Comment: @SandroKakhetelidze What I mean by "not changing the current route" means not navigating to a new screen, i.e. using [Jetpack Compose Navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation)

Comment: Dialog composable just shows a dialog in a new window with a composable view as its content. What you want to achieve is ability to draw outside of layout bounds. It is available in standard android UI toolkit via `clipToPadding="false"` and `clipChildren="false"` attributes. But as I understand, you want to enable some random view deep in the tree be able to draw outside its bounds ... I don't think it is possible in Android without making all layouts "clipChildren=false". The same for Compose.

Comment: I think having some global "render" that takes a composable and draws on top, is actually a not such a bad idea. It can be an object that you can make accessible to all hierarchy via `CompositionLocal`.

Comment: It will render just as another layer on top of the main tree. And you can even have many layers on top of each other. But than you will have to ensure you can manage it's state (kind of like window manager does it with window layers).

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I've implemented something similar before, but I did it poorly

Comment: Did u resolved it @foxtrotuniform6969?

Comment: I just droped a alternative to it, check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72496256/4563960

Answer (score 24):

From what I can tell you want to be able to draw from a nested hierarchy without being limited by the parent constraints.

We faced similar issues and looked at the implementation how Composables such as `Popup`, `DropDown` and `Dialog` function.

What they do is add an entirely new `ComposeView` to the `Window`.
Because of this they are basically starting from a blank canvas.
By making it transparent it looks like the Dialog/Popup/DropDown appears on top.

Unfortunately we could not find a Composable that provides us the functionality to just add a new `ComposeView` to the `Window` so we copied the relevant parts and made following.

```
@Composable
fun FullScreen(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val view = LocalView.current
    val parentComposition = rememberCompositionContext()
    val currentContent by rememberUpdatedState(content)
    val id = rememberSaveable { UUID.randomUUID() }

    val fullScreenLayout = remember {
        FullScreenLayout(
            view,
            id
        ).apply {
            setContent(parentComposition) {
                currentContent()
            }
        }
    }

    DisposableEffect(fullScreenLayout) {
        fullScreenLayout.show()
        onDispose { fullScreenLayout.dismiss() }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("ViewConstructor")
private class FullScreenLayout(
    private val composeView: View,
    uniqueId: UUID
) : AbstractComposeView(composeView.context) {

    private val windowManager =
        composeView.context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager

    private val params = createLayoutParams()

    override var shouldCreateCompositionOnAttachedToWindow: Boolean = false
        private set

    init {
        id = android.R.id.content
        ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(this, ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.get(composeView))
        ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.set(this, ViewTreeViewModelStoreOwner.get(composeView))
        ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.set(this, ViewTreeSavedStateRegistryOwner.get(composeView))

        setTag(R.id.compose_view_saveable_id_tag, "CustomLayout:$uniqueId")
    }

    private var content: @Composable () -> Unit by mutableStateOf({})

    @Composable
    override fun Content() {
        content()
    }

    fun setContent(parent: CompositionContext, content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
        setParentCompositionContext(parent)
        this.content = content
        shouldCreateCompositionOnAttachedToWindow = true
    }

    private fun createLayoutParams(): WindowManager.LayoutParams =
        WindowManager.LayoutParams().apply {
            type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_PANEL
            token = composeView.applicationWindowToken
            width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
            flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS or
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
        }

    fun show() {
        windowManager.addView(this, params)
    }

    fun dismiss() {
        disposeComposition()
        ViewTreeLifecycleOwner.set(this, null)
        windowManager.removeViewImmediate(this)
    }
}
```

Here is an example how you can use it

```
@Composable
internal fun Screen() {
    Column(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Red)
    ) {
        Text("Hello World")

        Box(Modifier.size(100.dp).background(Color.Yellow)) {
            DeeplyNestedComposable()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun DeeplyNestedComposable() {
    var showFullScreenSomething by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    TextButton(onClick = { showFullScreenSomething = true }) {
        Text("Show full screen content")
    }

    if (showFullScreenSomething) {
        FullScreen {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Color.Green)
            ) {
                Text("Full screen text", Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
                TextButton(onClick = { showFullScreenSomething = false }) {
                    Text("Close")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The yellow box has set some constraints, which would prevent the Composables from inside to draw outside its bounds.

[image]

Comment: I've been trying to use your solution to create my own custom Dialog with a configurable scrim color. I was able to create it, however if I clicked in any place of the screen that was not the Dismiss button, the Fullscreen would get frozen and could not dismiss it anymore. Do you have any idea why? @timr

Comment: Remembering the ```View``` calls are designed to target Jetpack Compose for Android, no support for Desktop in this.

Comment: The `R.id.compose_view_saveable_id_tag` is not recognized. Anything to import?

Comment: Looks like I can get it from `androidx.compose.ui.R.id.compose_view_saveable_id_tag`

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. in my case i couldn't interact with other views if part of my fullscreen is transparent. The fix is setting it to not focusable when calling show https://github.com/elye/demo_android_jetpack_compose_abstract_compose_view/blob/main/app/src/main/java/com/example/learnabstractcomposeview/MyComposeView.kt#L68

Answer (score 8):

Using the Dialog composable, I have been able to get a proper fullscreen Composable in any nested one. It's quicker and easier than some of other answers.

```
Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = { /* Do something when back button pressed */ },
    properties = DialogProperties(dismissOnBackPress = true, dismissOnClickOutside = false, usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)
){
    /* Your full screen content */
}
```

Comment: This is not full screen as the status bar is still visible.

Comment: in the solution from @timr the status bar is also visible, but fine for me. Both are good solutions imo. This seems to be a quick and easy solution

Comment: This is really hacky and easy, however ```Dialog``` seems to be platform dependent (specific implementaions to Android/Deesktop). In this case there's an solution to be more suitable between platforms?

Answer (score 3):

I've stopped using Popup as it does not easily draw the scrim over the status bar and navigation bar (the system bars).

Now I do the same with `Dialog`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/package-summary#dialog

```
@Composable
private fun PopupDialog(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit = {},
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
        properties = DialogProperties(
            dismissOnBackPress = true,
            dismissOnClickOutside = false,
            decorFitsSystemWindows = true,
        ),
    ) {
      Box(
        modifier
            .width(320.dp)
            .wrapContentHeight()
            .background(
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp)
            )
      ) {
        content()
      }
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
PopupDialog {
    Text("Hello World")
}
```

---

You can use a `Popup` for exactly that:

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/window/package-summary#Popup(androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupPositionProvider,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.window.PopupProperties,kotlin.Function0)

> Opens a popup with the given content. The popup is positioned using a
> custom popupPositionProvider.
>
> ```
> @Composable fun Popup(
>   popupPositionProvider: PopupPositionProvider,
>   onDismissRequest: (() -> Unit)? = null,
>   properties: PopupProperties = PopupProperties(),
>   content: @Composable () -> Unit 
> ): Unit
> ```

I made a composable like this. It can open from anywhere in the hierarchy and show something fill screen. This one shows a full-screen semi-transparent background and then some content:

```
@Composable
private fun MyPopup(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onDismiss: () -> Unit = {},
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    Popup(
        onDismissRequest = onDismiss,
        properties = PopupProperties(
            focusable = true,
            dismissOnBackPress = true,
        ),
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        ) {
            Canvas(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                drawRect(
                    color = Color(0xCC7D7D7D),
                    size = size,
                )
            }
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(320.dp)
                    .height(300.dp)
                    .background(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimary)
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
            ) {
                content()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like:

```
MyPopup {
    Text("Hello World")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you just don't want to navigate anywhere. Id something like this.

```
 when (val viewType = viewModel.viewTypeGallery.get()) {
        is GalleryViewModel.GalleryViewType.Gallery -> {
            Gallery(viewModel, scope, installId, filePathModifier, fragment, setImageUploadType)
        }
        is GalleryViewModel.GalleryViewType.ImageViewer -> {
            Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize(),
                    painter = rememberCoilPainter(viewType.imgUrl),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    contentDescription = null
                )
            }
        }
    }
```

I just keep track of what type the view is meant to be. In my case I'm not displaying a dialog I'm removing my entire gallery and showing an image instead.

Alternatively you could just have an if(viewImage) condition below your call your and layer the 'dialog' on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

After notice that, at least for now, we don't have any `Composable` to do "easy" fullscreen, I decided to implement mine one, mostly based on ideas from @foxtrotuniform6969 and @ntoskrnl. Also, I tried to do it most possible without to use platform dependent functions then I think this is very suiteable to Desktop/Android.

You can check the basic implementation in [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/LucasAlfare/FullscreenComposable).

By the way, the implementation idea was just:

- Create a composable to wrap the target composables tree that can call an `FullScreen` composable;
- Retrieve the full screen dimensions/size from a auxiliary `Box` matched to the root screen size using the `.onGloballyPositioned()` modifier;
- Store the full screen size and all `FullScreen` composables created in the tree onto appropriated `compositionLocalOf` instances (see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/compositionlocal)).

I tried to use this in a Desktop project and seems to be working, however I didn't tested in Android yet. The repository also contains a example.

Feel free to navigate in the repository and sent a pull request if you can. :)